# No puedo conseguir que imprima lo que quiero

Tags: python

Estoy intentando que solo me imprima por pantalla una vez lo que necesito pero me imprime cada vez que recorre el arreglo,

este es el código:

```
        for r in cliente:
        if r[0] == Busca:
            g=0
            existe=True
            g=g+1 
        elif existe == False:
                print("No se encontró cliente")
                print("Pulse enter para continuar")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que imprima que se encontró el cliente o no se encontró el cliente con solo 1 rut dependiendo de que si lo encuentra

Comment: El elif, debe ser un if fuera del bucle. al estar dentro, muestra el mensaje en cada cliente no encontrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, la verdad. A tener en cuenta, si lo que quieres es que, lo encuentre o no lo encuentre, salga del bucle para parar, o si te refieres a que una vez buscado todo, diga si está o no. En ese caso, no debe haber un `elif`si no un `if`comprobado si existe, fuera del bucle.

```
 for r in cliente:
        if r[0] == Busca:
            g=0
            existe=True
            g=g+1 
 if existe == False:
        print("No se encontró cliente")
        print("Pulse enter para continuar")
```

De todos modos, las variable `g` no tiene ningún uso (en el código que nos has mostrado), ni sabemos lo que es `cliente`, ni lo que es `Busca`.